# JAVAFX tab onCloseRequest consumes tabPane

Tags: java, javafx

```
tab.setOnCloseRequest(e -> {
                if (getEditorForTextArea(getSelectedTextArea()) != null){
                    selectedTextArea = getSelectedTextArea();
                    selectedEditor = getEditorForTextArea(selectedTextArea);
                    if (selectedEditor.isModified()){
                        if (DialogBox.newSaveConfirmationBox(tab.getText()))
                            saveFile();
                        else e.consume();
                    }
                }
            }
    );
```

This is my code. I wanted to pop up a `saveConfirmationBox` when `selectedEditor.isModified()`. Then a problem occured. I opened two tabs, one modified and another unmodified. When i am selecting the tab which is unmodified, I can close the modified tab with the X button without any confirmation. On the other hand, the confirmation box showed up when I am on the modified tab trying to close the unmodified one.

Here is how i get the `selectedEditor`:

```
private Editor getEditorForTextArea(TextArea textArea) {
    Iterator<Editor> editorIterator = editorVector.iterator();
    while (editorIterator.hasNext()) {
        Editor editor = editorIterator.next();
        if (textArea == editor.getRoot())
            return editor;
    }
    return null;
}

@Nullable
private TextArea getSelectedTextArea() {
    SingleSelectionModel<Tab> selectionModel = tabPane.getSelectionModel();
    if (selectionModel.isEmpty())   return null;
    Tab selectedTab = selectionModel.getSelectedItem();
    return (TextArea)selectedTab.getContent();
}
```

Thanks for help in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is totally expected behaviour because you are getting `TextArea` of **currently selected** tab in `getSelectedTextArea()` method. And so it checks `Editor` of currently selecetd tab, **not** the one that you are trying to close.

You should modify your `setOnCloseRequest` to comething like:

```
tab.setOnCloseRequest(e -> {
                if (getEditorForTextArea(getTextAreaFor(tab)) != null){
                    textArea = getTextAreaFor(tab);
                    editor = getEditorForTextArea(textArea);
                    if (editor.isModified()){
                        if (DialogBox.newSaveConfirmationBox(tab.getText()))
                            saveFile();
                        else e.consume();
                    }
                }
            }
    );
```

And the method `getTextAreaFor(tab)` will be

```
private TextArea getTextAreaFor(Tab tab) {
  return (TextArea)tab.getContent(); // with checks etc...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Vyacheslav Zhukov, here is my solution:

```
tab.setOnCloseRequest(e -> {
                if (getEditorForTextArea(getTextAreaForTab(tab)) != null){
                    Editor editorToClose = getEditorForTextArea(getTextAreaForTab(tab));
                    if (editorToClose.isModified()){
                        if (DialogBox.newSaveConfirmationBox(tab.getText()))
                            saveFile();
                        else e.consume();
                    }
                }
            }
    );

private TextArea getTextAreaForTab(Tab tab) {
    return (TextArea)tab.getContent();
//PS it won't be null lol nothing to check here :P
}
```